# Can period-finding algorithm obtain more-than-one period?

Tags: period-finding-algorithm

For instance, let $f$ be a function with two co-prime periods $p$ and $q$. Can we find both $p$ and $q$ with several quantum queries to $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function will have only 1 period $p$. What You can find is multiplicities of the period: $p,2p,3p,...$